# How to create nested array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I need to build an array look like this, that when you JSON.stringify in javascript it will look similar to this. How, please help

```
     [{
      name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
      data:[
             ['v11.0', 24.13],
             ['v8.0', 17.2],
             ['v9.0', 8.11],
             ['v10.0', 5.33],
             ['v6.0', 1.06],
             ['v7.0', 0.5] 
     ]}
```

How is the right way to do it?

```
$arr[] = array('name' => 'example', 'y' => 25, 'drill' => 'test', 'data :' => 
'["test" =>25]'  );

print_r $arr;
```

Also, I did this on my other part of code but its not nested. I cannot do it again because of the comma inside of the inner array is hard to trim out.

Comment: In json `[]` are arrays, `{}` are objects. So you'd need to create an array, with an object with those values.

Comment: Your brackets look a bit unbalanced at the beginning and end of your example JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array = []; 

$test = new stdClass();
$test->name = "Name";
$test->id = "Id";
$test->data = array("val1", "val2", "val3");

$array[] = $test;

echo json_encode($array); // [{"name":"Name","id":"Id","data":["val1","val2","val3"]}]
```

Comment: This is what i need

Comment: Glad to help, but this probably could have been solved by doing some research on understanding JSON a bit more. Feel free to mark it as the answer if it solves your issue, though.